# How to download a file with python-google-api

Tags: python, google-drive-api

How would I download a file using the GoogleAPI? Here is what I have so far:

```
CLIENT_ID = '255556'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'y8sR1'
DOCUMENT_ID = 'a123'
service=build('drive', 'v2')

# How to do the following line?
service.get_file(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, DOCUMENT_ID)
```

Comment: you need to get a user token first .... then you can get the file something like `redirect("http://api.google.com/authorize?client_id=255556&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:5000/result")` maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to download a file using Google Drive API. It depends on whether you are downloading a normal file or a google document (that needs to be exporteed in a specific format).

for regular files stored in drive, you can either use:

alt=media and it's the preferred option, as in:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs
```

the other method is to use DownloadUrl, as in:

```
from apiclient import errors
# ...

def download_file(service, drive_file):
  """Download a file's content.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    drive_file: Drive File instance.

  Returns:
    File's content if successful, None otherwise.
  """
  download_url = drive_file.get('downloadUrl')
  if download_url:
    resp, content = service._http.request(download_url)
    if resp.status == 200:
      print 'Status: %s' % resp
      return content
    else:
      print 'An error occurred: %s' % resp
      return None
  else:
    # The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return None
```

For google documents, instead of using downloadUrl, you need to use exportLinks and specify the mime type, for example:

```
download_url = file['exportLinks']['application/pdf']
```

The rest of the documentation can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads