# Google Drive URL download file

Tags: url, download, google-drive-api, http-get

I wonder what is the difference between URL for downloading file as below

1. method: using alt=media
   GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
   Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs
2. Alternate method: using downloadUrl
   GET https://doc-04-c1-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ivearmirmg66&e=download&gd=true
   Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs

Refer: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file

I tried to download large file (>2GB) and failed with method 1 (error 403 - quota of file is exceeded) but successful with method 2
So I do not know what is the difference behind these URL

Comment: Note: your first link uses drive v3 your linking to documentation for drive v2.

Comment: sorry I paste wrong link. But method 1 also drive v2 GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs

Answer (score 0):

Noting what DaImTo mentioned in the comments, the 1st method you included in the post is seen in [using alt=media](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#using_altmedia) in **v3** while [downloadUrl](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads#alternate_method_using_downloadurl) is for **v2** (although there is also a `using alt=media` seen for **v2**).

As I understand the [v2 docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file), `using alt=media` and `downloadUrl`, both have the same authentication and usage, `using alt=media` is the suggested and direct way to download a file while `downloadUrl` is (as seen in the docs) just an alternate (found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29975634/6124253) that shows some snippets where you can compare both). Also, for `downloadUrl`:

> The downloadUrl field is a **short-lived value** and is typically only good for 8 hours. For this reason, it's usually necessary to issue both requests around the same time. **The downloadUrl is not predictable by the client and must be fetched from the server metadata**.

Regarding the [error 403 - quota of file is exceeded](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_user_rate_limit_exceeded) you encounter, I'm not entirely sure why it works when using `downloadUrl` and not when `using alt=media`. But it might help if you can provide some of your code snippets. Regardless, as per the docs, the way to handle `error 403`s are:

> **403: Daily Limit Exceeded**
>
> Suggested action: Request additional quota.
>
> **403: User Rate Limit Exceeded**
>
> Suggested actions:
>
> - Raise the per-user quota in the Developer Console project.
> - If one user is making a lot of requests on behalf of many users of a Google Apps domain, consider a Service Account with authority delegation (setting the quotaUser parameter).
> - Use exponential backoff.
>
> **403: Rate Limit Exceeded**
>
> Suggested actions:
>
> - Batch the requests.
> - Use exponential backoff.

Note that this were from [docs v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors). There are other `403 error`s but I think only of the 3 above corresponds to what you are experiencing.